# Find occurrences of neighboring elements

Tags: python, list, sequence

Want to write a simple program that shoud count the number of occurrences of `"11"` in an input list of zeros and ones. The output should return a single number, which is the number of occurrences of `"11"`.

I have implemented the following code:

```
def count_ones(seq):
   # return the number of occurrences as a number
   return sum(1 for i in seq if i != 0)

print(count_ones([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])) # this should print 2
```

Now it doesn't work as needed. How to improve the given code to get a proper output?

Comment: Your current code just counts ones in the list. There's nothing to check that the next item is also a 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using zip

```
def count_ones(seq):
    # find pairs where current == next element == 1
    return sum(1 for x, y in zip(seq, seq[1:]) if x == y == 1)
```

**Tests**

```
print(count_ones([1, 0, 1])           # Output: 0
print(count_ones([1, 0, 1, 1])        # Output: 1
print(count_ones([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])) # Output: 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need (how could I forget zip?!). Thank you, @DarryIG!